# I want to solve this query with c program

Tags: c, if-statement

Can someone guide me how to put this properly in an if-else statement. 
Consider the following if statement, where `doesSignificantWork`, `makesBreakthrough`, and `nobelPrizeCandidate` are all boolean variables:

```
if (doesSignificantWork) {
    if (makesBreakthrough)
        nobelPrizeCandidate = true;
    else
        nobelPrizeCandidate = false;
}
else if (!doesSignificantWork)
    nobelPrizeCandidate = false;
```

First, write a simpler if statement that is equivalent to this one. Then write a single assignment statement that does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (doesSignificantWork) {
    if (makesBreakthrough)
        nobelPrizeCandidate = true;
    else
        nobelPrizeCandidate = false;
}
else if (!doesSignificantWork)
    nobelPrizeCandidate = false
```

Is equivalent to

```
nobelPrizeCandidate = (doesSignificantWork && makesBreakthrough);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). The first step is to identify inputs, and write down all combinations of their values.

```
Input   Output
d   m   n
0   0   ?
0   1   ?
1   0   ?
1   1   ?
```

Then fill the correct output values

```
Input   Output
d   m   n
0   0   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

You should now see that the output function corresponds to logical AND (`&&`).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler `if` statement is:

```
if (doesSignificantWork && makesBreakthrough)
  nobelPrizeCandidate = true;
else
  nobelPrizeCandidate = false;
```

@Blaze's answer gives you the simplest one-liner. An alternative is

```
nobelPrizeCandidate = (doesSignificantWork && makesBreakthrough) ? true : false;
```